Merging and looping data from two worksheets into one
I have a list of companies and a list of numbers in separate worksheets. The worksheets that contain the list of companies and numbers may change over time and become larger or smaller. I'm attempting to automate a process in excel where in a third worksheet (called Cost Centers), the company rows are duplicated by the count of numbers, then the numbers are repeated for each company.
Here is an example of the company worksheet:

Here is an example of the numbers worksheet:

And here is what the target output would look like:

Ideally, I could replace the values in company sheet or number sheet and it would auto refresh the cost center sheet.
